# List of tuples unpacking does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

I am aware of `*` operator but this one does not seem to work. I basically want to unpack this list consisting of tuple pairs:

```
sentence_list = [('noun', 'I'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('noun', 'princess')]
```

Consider my class **Sentence**:

```
class Sentence(object):

    def __init__(self, subject, verb, object):
        self.subject = subject[1]
        self.verb = verb[1]
        self.object = object[1]
```

Now I create an object called **test_obj** and when I try to unpack **sentence_list** it does not seem to work:

```
test_obj = Sentence(*sentence_list)
```

When I test it with `nose.tools` using:

```
assert_is_instance(test_obj, Sentence)
```

I get this:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

But when I change it to:

```
test_obj = Sentence(('noun', 'I'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('noun', 'princess'))
```

It passes the test. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are passing in a list of **two** elements, not 3, to get that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine, **provided** you actually pass in a list of 3 elements:

```
>>> class Sentence(object):
...     def __init__(self, subject, verb, object):
...         self.subject = subject[1]
...         self.verb = verb[1]
...         self.object = object[1]
... 
>>> sentence_list = [('noun', 'I'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('noun', 'princess')]
>>> Sentence(*sentence_list)
<__main__.Sentence object at 0x10043c0d0>
>>> del sentence_list[-1]
>>> Sentence(*sentence_list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Note the error message here; `__init__` takes *four* arguments, including `self`.

Ergo, it is your `sentence_list` value that is at fault here, not your technique.

Comment: Yes I've tried putting the code directly into interpreter. However how should I write the test so it passes?

Comment: @user3056783: You haven't shown us what `sentence_list` is in your test. It is **not** a list with enough elements.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm probably missing something here.. I'm still very new to programming, it's `sentence_list = [('noun', 'I'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('noun', 'princess')]` like I wrote before.

My test file is something like this:

from nose.tools import *
import p

sentence_list = [('noun', 'I'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('noun', 'princess')]

def test_parse_subject_class():
 test_obj = p.Sentence(*sentence_list)
 assert_is_instance(test_obj, p.Sentence)
 assert_equal(test_obj.subject, 'I')

Where `p` is other module where the actual code is. I'm using `nosetests` to test it.

Comment: @user3056783: You'll want to print `sentence_list` then, because the *only* way you are getting your exception is if `sentence_list` contains two and not 3 elements. Add a `print` statement just before invoking `Sentence(*sentence_list)` (making sure you run `nose -s` so stdout is not being captured) and see what is being printed.

Comment: Hmm you are right it prints out this at the beginning:

`........[('verb', 'kill'), ('noun', 'princess')]
E.......
======================================================================
ERROR: p_test.test_parse_subject_class`

Comment: @user3056783: See, now you know what to debug! :-)

Comment: OK I think I found a mistake... I've probably done newbie mistake. `sentence_list` is used in numerous test functions. Some of the functions contain `list.pop` and those tests run first. So when this test, which is at the end of the test file runs, the list is different.

I've created new list that is contained within the test function and the test passes.

I feel really stupid for not noticing but I feel like I learned from this.

Comment: You have what is called a test isolation bug; the bug isn't there in isolation, but when you run multiple tests your test breaks. Don't reuse data between tests. ;-)

Comment: Yes it seems logical now :) I am still trying to figure out this testing thing because up until now I've been learning how to minimize code... seems like the same approach is not smart for testing.